# IE6 Prompt to Download Flash

Tags: flash

How can I get IE6 to prompt to install Flash if the user does not have it installed? I cannot use swfobject. My current code is:

```
<object width="370" height="506" id="a" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                    <param value="movie.swf" name="movie">
                    <param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
                    <param value="high" name="quality">
                    <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
                    <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
                    <embed width="370" height="506" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" src="movie.swf" name="a" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="a">

                </object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Adobe Flash Detection Kit](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/)